# Ballpark energy consumption per state transition for a D-flipflop in a modern chip manufacturing process?

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, energy

For a D-flip-flop in a modern yet-not-too-extravagant chip manufacturing process (let's say 28nm or 40nm), what are some ballpark figures for the energy cost per switching H->L or L->H one can expect?

Probably it will also depend on the load that is driven, temperature, supply voltage, specific process etc. but I'm looking for a back-of-the-envelope figure here, just to get a rough idea.

I found this earlier: [Low power double edge triggered flipflop](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3377687_Low-power_double-edge_triggered_flipflop/figures), where Figure 6 seems to suggest that at 500MHz, 50% switching activity, one can expect roughly 8uW,or **16fJ** (femto Joule). Does this sound realistic?

Comment: you can estimate it if you can find numbers for the total gate charge or gate capacitance (x supply voltage). Multiply by the number of the gates in the flipflop. from the back of my head: the gate capacitance is in the 0.x fF range.

Comment: I can't access this paper, but given that it's from 1997, it will not likely describe a 28-40nm process. The easiest way to get device information from advanced process nodes without signing for anything is to use the ASU predictive technology models (http://ptm.asu.edu/).

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic power loss in CMOS D FF’s made of TG’s and inverters may be computed as follows:

[image]
[Ref](https://rocelec.widen.net/view/pdf/3dcfkklbla/NEXP-S-A0003511411-1.pdf)
Cpd=17 pF, Vcc(min)= 1.65V, f(typ)= 250 MHz, Cin(typ) = 5 pF ( use for min load)

Comment: Thanks. For minimum Vcc=1.65V, no load, that would calculate to about 46pJ per transition, if not mistaking. Seems a lot.

Comment: . That’s equiv to the energy of storing 31 pF @ 1.65V twice per cycle in lossless charging of 10.3 pF with charge reversal and twice the energy dissipated in RdsOn. So it’s reasonable.